# Sort a list of objects to put parents first

Tags: java, sorting, tree

I have a class which contains a reference to a parent of the same type( or null if it has no parent).

> ```
> class MyObject{
>     private MyObject parent;
>     public MyObject getParent(){ return parent};
>     …
> }
> ```

I have a list of MyObject, and need to order it so that every object comes after its parent in the list (the parent will always be in the list).

```
void orderList(List<MyObject> toSort){
    List<MyObject> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
    while(!toSort.isEmpty()) {
        for(MyObject obj: toSort){
            if(obj.getParent() == null) {
                tmp.add(obj);
            }else {
                if(tmp.contains(obj.getParent())) {
                    tmp.add(obj);
                }
            }
        }
        toSort.removeAll(tmp);
    }
    toSort.addAll(tmp);
}
```

Is there a way to make this function more efficient and readable ?

Comment: What is **`info`** in the code?

Comment: a mistake, it was supposed to be obj.

Comment: Did you run it? It should fail into **`ConcurrentModificationException`** as soon as you **`removeAll`** from **`toSort`** while the for loop is iterating it.

Comment: Sorry, the removeAll was meant to be outside the for loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make this faster quite a bit (in complexity terms) by precomputing which objects have which parent and then successively building your list instead of iterating all objects with pure chance. Your complexity in the worst case right now is \$O(n^3)\$. (n^2 for the nested loops, another n for the `contains`)

Consider the following:

```
void orderList(List<MyObject> toSort) {
    final MyObject nullPlaceholder = new MyObject();
    Map<MyObject, List<MyObject>> byParent = toSort.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(obj -> 
           (obj.getParent() == null ? nullPlaceholder : obj.getParent())
           , Collectors.toList()));

    List<MyObject> ordered = new ArrayList<>();
    Queue<MyObject> processor = new LinkedList<>();
    byParent.get(nullPlaceholder).forEach(processor::add);
    while (!processor.isEmpty()) {
        MyObject tmp = processor.poll();
        byParent.getOrDefault(tmp, Collections.emptyList())
          .forEach(processor::add);
        ordered.add(tmp);
    }
    toSort.clear();
    toSort.addAll(ordered);
}
```

**Notes:**

- You menitioned in comments, that null-keys are not supported in the `groupingBy` collector. This code works around by creating a "null object". more info at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)
- `getOrDefault` works around the fact that the last `MyObject`s won't have "children", meaning that they don't have elements in the map. With standard `get` that would return `null`. You could manually check, but that breaks the flow IMO, and I prefer it like this :)

This should boil down to a runtime complexity of \$O(n)\$, which should give you **significant** performance boosts for larger lists.

In addition to that I dislike reusing references you receive as input. I *personally* prefer to use value-returning methods instead of modifying references. As such I'd adjust your method to return a `List<MyObject>` and `return ordered;` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is to organize the objects into a tree, after which you would run the breadth-first search starting from the root node, and descending into the child nodes of each processed node. Here's how:

```
public static void orderList2(List<MyObject> toSort) {
    Map<MyObject, List<MyObject>> parentMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (MyObject obj : toSort) {
        if (!parentMap.containsKey(obj.getParent())) {
            parentMap.put(obj.getParent(), new ArrayList<>());
        }

        parentMap.get(obj.getParent()).add(obj);
    }

    if (parentMap.get(null) == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The input is not a tree.");
    }

    Deque<MyObject> queue = new ArrayDeque<>(parentMap.get(null));
    toSort.clear();

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        MyObject current = queue.removeFirst();
        toSort.add(current);
        List<MyObject> children = parentMap.get(current);

        if (children != null) {
            queue.addAll(children);
        }
    }
}
```

Clearly, constructing the tree takes \$\Theta(n)\$, and so does the breadth-first search, yielding the \$\Theta(n)\$ running time for the entire algorithm.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is a full-on copy of my answer's approach, half an hour later. What benefits does your answer have over mine?

Comment: @Vogel612 Alternative beginner-friendly implementation.

Comment: If I have a forest, not a tree, is it enough to modify the check `!parentMap.containsKey(obj.getParent())` to `obj.getParent()==null || !parentMap.containsKey(obj.getParent())`?

Answer (score 0):

Without extra conditions you could have a list `[ B(parent=A), D(parent=C) ]`. ***That would not get sorted***, I think, even if needed: `A(parent:C)`.

In fact you have a partial ordering. One solution:

```
list.sort((x, y) -> Integer.compare(depth(x), depth(y));
```

with

```
int depth(MyObject obj) {
    int ancestorsAndMe = 0;
    while (obj != null) {
        ++ancestorsAndMe;
        obj = obj.parent;
    }
    return ancestorsAndMe;
}
```

The would give a list with nodes of depth 1, then with depth 2, then 3 and so on.

The complexity is terrible in this naive solution, as sorting would recalculate the depth, but a simple datastructure will give \$O(N.TreeDepth)\$.